# How to validate the email using html only?

Tags: html, email

I have an email type textbox. i entered some character in that text box. When i focus out the text have to validate the email id without using jquery , javascript, angularJS, etc.... please suggest the solution.

Comment: Use the [HTML5 email input](https://www.wufoo.com/html5/types/1-email.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have to set limitation for after dot(.). How to implement. For example i have allow only maximum 5 characters(some@gmail.cooom) after dot(.) , otherwise should through error.

Comment: @Gopal why do you limit? If you don't have specific reasons, I don't suggest to limit it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains here you can see list of TLDs. Some of them has more than 5 letters.

Comment: i did the application for single organization. have to allow that organization mails only. others have to restrict. For that reason i have used.

Answer (score 3):

```html
<form>
<input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,63}$" required />
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

then you can use HTML5 input email validation without using jquery , javascript, angularJS, etc

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have to set limitation for after dot(.). How to implement. For example i have allow only maximum 5 characters(some@gmail.cooom) after dot(.) , otherwise should through error.

Comment: have to show error on text box focus out , not in submit click

Comment: check the edited snippet,for this(set limitation for after dot(.)) also add pattern for email validation  with required attribute so that it will also validate when the field is empty.

Comment: validation functionality was ok. but it should validate when textbox focus out not in submit. is it possible?

Comment: @Gopal not with only HTML.

Comment: @gopal: is there any limitation for adding validation only by HTML?

Comment: That's my question. Is it possible or not?

Comment: in HTML validation on focus it's just indicate so for showing error message on validation you should use javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `email` type in your input. It is an HTML5 standart input type that browsers auto-validate its value. Also `input`s have `pattern` attribute which can be used to validate data with custom specifications.

Below, there are 2 examples. First input accepts only TLDs with a length between 2 and 5. Second input accepts only TLDs which are exactly .design

```html
<form>
  E-mail (TLD max 5):
  <input type="email" name="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,5}$" required="required">
  <br/> E-mail (TLD only = .design):
  <input type="email" name="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.design" required="required">
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Comment: With required otherwise user can leave this field blank

Comment: It accept below mail id?
sometext@organization.design

Answer (score 0):

With html5 you can use type attribute of input as email for email validation.

`<input type="email" />`

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp

If you want some more sophistication you can use regex in patter attribute of input.

`<input pattern="Your_Email_Regex" type="email" />`

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have to set limitation for after dot(.). How to implement. For example i have allow only maximum 5 characters(some@gmail.cooom) after dot(.) , otherwise should through error.

Comment: Email regex are not universal and everybody uses according to their own need.
/^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/
This is the one I use in my code. For more fiddling you can go and create your own at regexr.com

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below form for email

```html
<form name='f1' method="POST" action=""  >     
    Email: <input type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Enter mailID" required pattern="[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{1,63}$" autofocus >
    <input type="submit"  name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have to set limitation for after dot(.). How to implement. For example i have allow only maximum 5 characters(some@gmail.cooom) after dot(.) , otherwise should through error.

Comment: have to show error when focus out the email text box, not in submit @shital

Comment: add autofocus attributes

Comment: autofocus used for focus only when page open

Comment: Did you understand my question? otherwise i will explain @shital